# Multiple html elements target a single js event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have multiple posts on a page and each post contains a delete button for deleting the post. Each post has a unique id. I want to delete the post using ajax.

So, I need to create different jquery event listeners for each post.

Here is what actually, I'm doing:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
    <h1>$post->some_field</h1>
    <a href="#" id="deletePost{{$post->id}}">delete</a>

    <script>
        $('#deletePost{{$post->id}}').on('click', function(){
            // create confirm dialog
            // delete the post with id {{$post->id}}
        })
    </script>
@endforeach
```

The javascript code is created for each post. Is there any way that, so that I can define the listener once at the bottom and all the delete button executes that event with different values.

I mean after clicking the delete button, it will give me the id of the post and I will delete that post.

Comment: Use the class selector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Class Selector `('.class')`](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) to attach event handler and custom `data-*` attribute to persist arbitrary data i.e. *post id* which can be retried by using [`.data(key)`](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data2) method.

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
    <h1>$post->some_field</h1>
    <a href="#" data-id="{{$post->id}}" class="deletePost">delete</a>
@endforeach

<script>
    $('.deletePost').on('click', function(){
        // delete the post with id {{$post->id}}
        var postId = $(this).data('id')
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The alternative to adding an event listener to *every* delete button (depending on how many posts there are) is to add a parent container for the posts, perhaps called `.posts`, attach a single event to that element, and use event delegation to catch events from the button clicks as they bubble up the DOM. This is called [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

```js
$('.posts').on('click', '.delete', function() {
  const $post = $(this).parent();
  const id = $post.data('id');
  console.log(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="posts">
  <article data-id="1">
    <button class="delete">Delete</button>
  </article>
  <article data-id="2">
    <button class="delete">Delete</button>
  </article>
  <article data-id="3">
    <button class="delete">Delete</button>
  </article>
</section>
```